# Is there any way to access an iTunes library to set an alarm tone?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any way to access an iTunes library to set an alarm tone?

I am building an alarm app. I think we can can use local notifications when my app is in the background, but it can't play music library sounds. So when the app is in foreground, I want to play sounds from the music library and songs from my app bundle as well. How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the music libray of your device using the `MPMusicPlayerController`.
For this you need to include the `MediaPlayer.framework` framework and `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` header file.

You will get the picked music url using this delegate method (for this you need to add the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` in @interface) :

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
}
```

Refer this [tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/) for a detailed description.